# How to find the length of an array in shell?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

How do I find the length of an array in shell?

For example:

```
arr=(1 2 3 4 5)
```

And I want to get its length, which is 5 in this case.

Answer (score 282):

```
$ a=(1 2 3 4)
$ echo ${#a[@]}
4
```

Comment: What does `@` do here?

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar There's a decent explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3355375/1858225). Basically, `[*]` and `[@]` both "explode" arrays into a tokenized string, but `[@]` can preserve spaces *within* tokens. However, when *counting* elements, it doesn't appear to matter; `arr=(foo "bar baz"); echo ${arr[*]}` prints `2`, not `3`.

Comment: This worked for me but only after removing `[@]` on Mac. `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)` if anyone's having the same issue.

Comment: Without the `[@]` it returns the length of the first element for me (using Bash 4.4.20(1)-release).

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne I tested `${#a[@]}` in bash 2.00.0(2) (the oldest version I could compile. This is from 1996!) and bash 3.2.57(1) (the version used on macOS). The command worked as expected in both version. I guess you must have made an error somewhere else.

Comment: @Socowi I just checked it as standalone and it works for me as well, it was probably somewhere else on the script that conflicted the `[`.

Comment: @KyleStrand probably meant `${#arr[*]}` instead of `${arr[*]}` there, which I have cnofirmed indeed prints 2, tested on bash 5.0.3(1)

Answer (score 48):

From Bash [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ${#parameter}
>
> The length in characters of the expanded value of parameter is substituted. If parameter is ‘`*`’ or ‘`@`’, the value substituted is the
> number of positional parameters. If parameter is an array name
> subscripted by ‘`*`’ or ‘`@`’, the value substituted is the number of
> elements in the array. If parameter is an indexed array name
> subscripted by a negative number, that number is interpreted as
> relative to one greater than the maximum index of parameter, so
> negative indices count back from the end of the array, and an index of
> -1 references the last element.

## Length of strings, arrays, and associative arrays

```
string="0123456789"                   # create a string of 10 characters
array=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)           # create an indexed array of 10 elements
declare -A hash
hash=([one]=1 [two]=2 [three]=3)      # create an associative array of 3 elements
echo "string length is: ${#string}"   # length of string
echo "array length is: ${#array[@]}"  # length of array using @ as the index
echo "array length is: ${#array[*]}"  # length of array using * as the index
echo "hash length is: ${#hash[@]}"    # length of array using @ as the index
echo "hash length is: ${#hash[*]}"    # length of array using * as the index
```

output:

```
string length is: 10
array length is: 10
array length is: 10
hash length is: 3
hash length is: 3
```

## Dealing with `$@`, the argument array:

```
set arg1 arg2 "arg 3"
args_copy=("$@")
echo "number of args is: $#"
echo "number of args is: ${#@}"
echo "args_copy length is: ${#args_copy[@]}"
```

output:

```
number of args is: 3
number of args is: 3
args_copy length is: 3
```

Answer (score 28):

Assuming bash:

```
~> declare -a foo
~> foo[0]="foo"
~> foo[1]="bar"
~> foo[2]="baz"
~> echo ${#foo[*]}
3
```

So, `${#ARRAY[*]}` expands to the length of the array `ARRAY`.

Comment: This question is pretty old but I would like to know how to store this length of array in one variable? I tried something like foo=${#foo[*]} but shell is throwing `command not found` error.

Comment: What is `*`? How does it differ from `@`?

Comment: @jameshfisher It doesn't, in this usage.

Answer (score 9):

in tcsh or csh:

```
~> set a = ( 1 2 3 4 5 )
~> echo $#a
5
```

Comment: None of the above working for me ! This works perfect!! Could you please more detail??

Answer (score 6):

In the [Fish Shell](https://fishshell.com/) the length of an array can be found with:

```
$ set a 1 2 3 4
$ count $a
4
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a `count` command in Unix.  Which OS are you using?

Comment: @codeforester It's a shell command, obviously available in the Fish shell. OS doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 5):

This works well for me:

```
arglen=$#
argparam=$*
if [ $arglen -eq '3' ];
then
    echo Valid Number of arguments
    echo "Arguments are $*"
else
    echo only four arguments are allowed
fi
```

Answer (score -4):

For those who still searching a way to put the length of an array into a variable:

```
foo="${#ARRAY[*]}"
```

Comment: This is the right, short answer

Comment: Ironically, this is almost identical to the most upvoted answer.