# Length of a sequence of numbers using seq in shell

Tags: bash, shell, seq

I am new to shell scripting and I am trying a simple task of getting the length of a sequence of numbers generated using `seq`.

With the help of a related post here: [How to find the array length in unix shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886374/how-to-find-the-array-length-in-unix-shell) I was able to do this -

```
a=(1 2 3 4 5)
echo ${#a[@]}  #length of a
5              #length of a = 5 (This is fine !!)
```

However when I try to do a similar thing using `seq` ..

```
b=$(seq 1 1 10)
echo $b
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
echo ${#b[@]}
1              #the length of b is 1, while I expect it to be 10
```

Why does this happen ? Are the variable types a and b different? is b not an array ?

I am sure I am missing something very trivial here, help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Ashwin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to store the output in an array to find the length of the array:

```
$ b=($(seq 1 1 10))
$ echo ${#b[@]}
10
```

Saying `b=$(seq 1 1 10)` doesn't produce an array.

Answer (score 3):

Try

`echo ${b[0]}`

It will be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 because all your values are stored in first element of array a as a string.

```
b=($(seq 1 1 10))
```

will do what you want.