# "operand expected (error token is "#") - Error when using hash arrays in a for loop

Tags: bash

Here is my code:

```
readarray -d '' sumarray < <(find . -iname '*.sum' -print0 | sort -z)
readarray -d '' maparray < <(find . -iname '*.edit2' -print0 | sort -z)

for ((i = 0; i < ${maparray[#]}; i++)); do
    paste <(cut -d , -f 3 -s "${sumarray[$i]}") <(cut -f 2 -s "${maparray[$i]}") > "${sumarray[$i]/.csv/.merged.csv}"
done
```

I have TSV and CSV files, in pairs where their filenames share the same ID's in them. I am combining specific columns from each of those files to make a new CSV file. I have put the files into a sorted array. I have a for loop to create a new CSV file for every pair.

The error I am getting is:

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is "#")
```

I am also running bash version 4.4 so readarray -d defintely works.
I have also tested the paste command and it works fine. 
I think the error is in the `for` line, but I am not sure what

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886374/how-to-find-the-length-of-an-array-in-shell

Comment: Should be `${#maparray}`.

Comment: I know you got that from another answer I wrote. I made a mistake.

Comment: Actually, `${#maparray[@]}`. Sorry again.

Comment: Hey @Barmar , Thanks for your input again. I now get a ${#sumarray[$i]/.csv/.merged.csv}: bad substitution error. Do you think using sed would help to edit the file name?

Comment: Why did you put `#` there? It should only be in the `for` line. Do you understand what it's for? Have you read the documentation of arrays in bash?

Comment: No, that was a typo, ignore that.

Comment: I have a cut error, no such file or directory. I echo the contents of the arrays and they are populated. I have read the documentation, nothing in there was helpful with this error.