# shell command with progress bar

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to ask you an small question,
if i have this progress bar from https://github.com/fearside/ProgressBar/

```
    #!/bin/bash
# 1. Create ProgressBar function
# 1.1 Input is currentState($1) and totalState($2)
function ProgressBar {
# Process data
    let _progress=(${1}*100/${2}*100)/100
    let _done=(${_progress}*4)/10
    let _left=40-$_done
# Build progressbar string lengths
    _fill=$(printf "%${_done}s")
    _empty=$(printf "%${_left}s")

# 1.2 Build progressbar strings and print the ProgressBar line
# 1.2.1 Output example:
# 1.2.1.1 Progress : [########################################] 100%
printf "\rProgress : [${_fill// /#}${_empty// /-}] ${_progress}%%"

}

# Variables
_start=1

# This accounts as the "totalState" variable for the ProgressBar function
_end=100

# Proof of concept
for number in $(seq ${_start} ${_end})
do
    sleep 0.1
    ProgressBar ${number} ${_end}
done
printf '\nFinished!\n'
```

where in this code i can combine in  my loop?

```
for i in `cat server`
do ssh -o "BatchMode=yes" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $i " (df -h /var | tr '\n' ',') & (hostname)| tr '\n' ',' " ;echo 2>&1 | tee >> /tmp/check_var2.csv

done
```

Comment: What kind of progress you want to show? How many lines have been read from the file `server`?

Comment: the command was just an example.. i want it to show the loop progress after i run it ( some commands are taking time such as cleaning the inodes or naking other things.. )   , and it is about 2 lines, of 2 servers ( server list)

Answer (score 2):

It is everything here already.

[Create an array from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30988586/402322):

```
mapfile -t server < server
```

[Take the size of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1886374/402322):

```
end=${#server[@]}
```

[Loop over an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash):

```
for (( i=1; i <= end; i++ )); do
  ProgressBar "$i" "$end"
  echo do something
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the for loops as such:

```sh
X=0
SERVERS=($(cat server))
for i in "${SERVERS[@]}"; do
    ssh -o "BatchMode=yes" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $i " (df -h /var | tr '\n' ',') & (hostname)| tr '\n' ',' " ;echo 2>&1 | tee >> /tmp/check_var2.csv
    ((X=X+1))
    ProgressBar ${X} ${#SERVERS[@]}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way (see code comments for detail):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Servers file
declare -r servers='servers'

# Prepare the CSV output file
declare -r csv_out='/tmp/check_var2.csv'
rm -f "$csv_out"
# Print the first CSV line with headers
echo 'Filesystem,Size,Used,Avail,Use%,Mounted on,Hostname' >"$csv_out"

# Prepare commands script sent to remote servers via ssh
# Produces CSV data:
# Filesystem,Size,Used,Avail,Use%,Mounted on,Hostname
declare -- ssh_script
IFS= read -r -d '' ssh_script <<'EOF'
{
  df -h /var | tail -n 1
  hostname
} | xargs | tr ' ' ','
EOF
typeset -r ssh_script

# Fills the servers_array from the servers file
declare -a serv_array
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d ' ' -a serv_array <"$servers"

# Get the size of the servers array
declare -ri serv_size="${#serv_array[@]}"

# Fixed progress-bar version
progress_bar() {
  local -r width=40
  local bar
  local left
  # Build string lengths
  printf -v bar "%$((${1}*width/${2}))s"
  printf -v left "%$((width-${1}*width/${2}))s"

  # Build and print the progress bar
  # Output example: [########################################] 100%
  printf "\rProgress : [%s%s] %d%%" "${bar// /#}" "${left// /-}" $((${1}*100/${2}))
}

# Iterate index of servers
for ((i = 0; i < serv_size; i++)); do
  server="${serv_array[i]}"
  ssh \
    -o "BatchMode=yes" \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    "$server" \
    "$ssh_script" \
    >>"$csv_out"
  progress_bar "$((i + 1))" "$serv_size"
done

echo
```